# cant search on multiple types in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this query:

```
GET /peopledb/person/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 2,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "personId": "harp"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase_prefix": {
            "name": "43"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase_prefix": {
            "personAddress.city": "harp"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "personAddress.street": "harp"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "personAddress.streetNumber": "harp"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "filter": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "type": {
            "name": "text"
          }
        },
        {
          "type": {
            "personAddress.streetNumber": "long"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

which `name` for example is text and `personAddress.streetNumber` is long, and if I use this query to and put "23" it works and find `streenNumber` where is 23, but if I put "john" i get and error, cause probably es trying to change "john" to long and it fails, so how do I go by this here?

the only thing i want is to be able to receive text query from a client side and search for it in those fields...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use full text search only against fields with type "text". All fields with other type (numeric, date and so on) should be placed in the filter clause.

Let's suppose you have an index `peopledb` with type `person` with default mapping. In `peopledb` index you have two documents:

```
{
  "personId": "wheeler",
  "name": "Frank Wheeler",
  "personAddress": {
    "city": "New York",
    "street": "Revolutionary road",
    "streetNumber": 115
  }
}
```

and

```
{
  "personId": "harper",
  "name": "John Harper",
  "personAddress": {
    "city": "Glasgow",
    "street": "Craigiehall Street",
    "streetNumber": 32 
  }
```

}

You can easily do full text search accross text fields:

```
"query": {
  "multi_match": {
    "query": "frank harper",
    "fields": ["name", "personAddress.city", "personAddress.street"]
  }
}
```

This query will return you all two records from index. But if you want to find document where `streetNumber` is 115 you cannot just edit your query and include `personAddress.streetNumber` into the fields array since type of `streetNumber` field is scalar and it does not make much sense to do full text search accross scalar fields. Instead you should add a filter clause:

```
"query": {
  "bool": {
    "must": {
      "multi_match": {
        "query": "frank harper",
        "fields": ["name", "personAddress.city", "personAddress.street"]
      }
    },
    "filter": {
      "term": {
        "personAddress.streetNumber": "115"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: edited my query in the question, is this supposed to work? i get an error ```reason": "Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [filter]."```

Comment: @JohnBigs I've just edited my answer. I hope it will clarify a little bit how to use filters.

Comment: thank so much for the great answer. let me ask you one last question. about the last part with the scalar fields: so how should I go by with the fact that i just got from the client-side some input, it can be "harper", and it can be "115", i dont know what im gonna get, and I want to give them the ability of autocomplete.., in the client side its one text-field where that you can search streetNumber/name/...

Comment: @JohnBigs One of the options is to use `_all` field (look at the Elasticsearch [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html)).